# Finding percentage difference from different values in the same SQL Table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that tracks total values for months against years in a particular location.

Desired Outcome: I wanted to compare a month's value for the current year against last years value. I then wanted to check for a percentage increase.

e.g. 2014 (January) = 140 - 2013 (January) = 150 * 100 = - 6.67

Table Name- donation_tracker

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Sql-Server?   You've tagged both.

Comment: Oops just MySQL I didn't mean to click Sql-Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you need to compare the immediately-completed twelve months with the twelve months prior to that, month-by-month. I am guessing at your table and column names because, well, I don't know them.

Let's build this from the ground up.

Here's a query that will find the most recent twelve months of donations month by month.

```
SELECT YEAR(donation_date) AS donation_year, 
       MONTH(donation_date) AS donation_month,
       SUM(donation_amount) AS donation_amount
  FROM donations
 WHERE donation_date >= LAST_DAY(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 13 MONTH
   AND donation_date <  LAST_DAY(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
 GROUP BY YEAR(donation_date), MONTH(donation_date)
```

That gives you a twelve-row result set like this (when NOW() happens to be in the middle of November 2014):

```
2013  11    145
2013  12    220
2014   1    123
2014   2     11
  ...
2014  10     45
```

The trick is picking the right range of `donation_date` values.

So, now you need two of those result sets, one for mostly-2014 and one for mostly-2013.  The one for mostly-2013 looks very similar. You simply back up one more year like this.

```
SELECT YEAR(donation_date) AS donation_year, 
       MONTH(donation_date) AS donation_month,
       SUM(donation_amount) AS donation_amount
  FROM donations
 WHERE donation_date >= LAST_DAY(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 25 MONTH
   AND donation_date <  LAST_DAY(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 13 MONTH
 GROUP BY YEAR(donation_date), MONTH(donation_date)
```

This is going to be one of those notorious club-sandwich queries, made of those two basic queries. You join them by month like so, then do the percentage computation in the SELECT clause.

```
SELECT a.donation_month, 
       a.donation_amount AS this_year, 
       b.donation_amount AS last_year,
       100.0 * (a.donation_amount - b.donation_amount) / b.donation_amount as pct_increase
  FROM (
          /* this year's query */
       ) AS a 
  JOIN (
          /* last year's query */
       ) AS b ON a.donation_month = b.donation_month 
  ORDER BY a.donation_year, a.donation_month
```

Here's the whole club sandwich for your server to chew on. Yummy!

```
SELECT a.donation_month, 
       a.donation_amount AS this_year, 
       b.donation_amount AS last_year,
       100.0 * (a.donation_amount - b.donation_amount) / b.donation_amount as pct_increase
  FROM (
        SELECT YEAR(donation_date) AS donation_year, 
               MONTH(donation_date) AS donation_month,
               SUM(donation_amount) AS donation_amount
          FROM donations
         WHERE donation_date >= LAST_DAY(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 13 MONTH
           AND donation_date <  LAST_DAY(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL  1 MONTH
         GROUP BY YEAR(donation_date), MONTH(donation_date) 
       ) AS a 
  JOIN (
        SELECT YEAR(donation_date) AS donation_year, 
               MONTH(donation_date) AS donation_month,
               SUM(donation_amount) AS donation_amount
          FROM donations
         WHERE donation_date >= LAST_DAY(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 25 MONTH
           AND donation_date <  LAST_DAY(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 13 MONTH
         GROUP BY YEAR(donation_date), MONTH(donation_date) 
       ) AS b ON a.donation_month = b.donation_month 
  ORDER BY a.donation_year, a.donation_month
```

Once you stack up the whole club sandwich, it look complicated. But it's actually a stack of simple subqueries.

Answer (score 4):

As I understood, You want to get the **percent of increase from last year to current year for the Same month for a Particular location**. Use the query.

```
SELECT D1.month, ROUND((D2.Donation_amount- D1.Donation_amount) * 100 / 
       D1.Donation_amount, 2)
FROM       donation_tracker D1
INNER JOIN donation_tracker D2 
ON d1.month = D2.month AND D1.year = D2.year - 1 
                       AND D1.Location_ID = D2.Location_ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give you an idea :)

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (`month` varchar(3), `year` int, `amount` int)
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`month`, `year`, `amount`)
VALUES
    ('jan', 2013, 150),
    ('feb', 2013, 180),
    ('jan', 2014, 140),
    ('feb', 2014, 160)
;
```

Query:

```
select
t1.month, round((t2.amount - t1.amount) * 100 / t1.amount, 2)
from
t t1
inner join t t2 on t1.month = t2.month and t1.year < t2.year;
```

Result:

```
| MONTH | ROUND((T2.AMOUNT - T1.AMOUNT) * 100 / T1.AMOUNT, 2) |
|-------|-----------------------------------------------------|
|   jan |                                               -6.67 |
|   feb |                                              -11.11 |
```